# JQuery variables inside loop recalled by name calculation... possible?

Tags: jquery, variables, loops

The following loop generates a variable for each div element with class .scrollable

```
var scrolls[];

$('.scrollable').each(function(){
                            this.id = 'scrollp' + (++orderit);
                            scrolls[ 'myScroll' + this.id ] = this.id;
                        });
```

The problem is that I need to call them again later, and we do not know which ID was assigned where. I tried this.

```
setTimeout(function () {
                  $('.scrollable').each(function(){
                        scrolls[ 'myScroll' + $(this).attr('id')]_update();
                  });
                  }, 2500);
```

But the variable is unknown. FIREBUG:: missing before statement. I take it that it cannot work out the variable name like that, but have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Why is there a underscore before update() ?

Comment: That is how the plugin works. eg. oScrollbar5.tinyscrollbar_update();  http://www.baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$('.scrollable').each(function(){
    $(this).tinyscrollbar_update(); 
});
```

Comment: Returned this error on FIREBUG:: $(this).data("tsb") is undefined
[Break On This Error] (function($){$.tiny=$.tiny||{};$.tiny....f.update();setEvents();return oSelf;}

Comment: Without more code I can't help. What I posted is how to properly update an initialized tinyscrollbar. It looks like the object from you selector is not actually a tinyscrollbar, but that is a guess.

Comment: that because you are trying to update the whole htmlcollection array try my loop instead

Answer (score 0):

I think this:

```
setTimeout(function () {
              $('.scrollable').each(function(){
                    scrolls[ 'myScroll' + $(this).attr('id')]_update();
              });
              }, 2500);
```

Should be:

```
setTimeout(function () {
              $('.scrollable').each(function(){
                    scrolls[ 'myScroll' + $(this).attr('id')].tinyscrollbar_update();
              });
              }, 2500);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each( $( '.scrollable' ), function( index, element ){
    $( element ).tinyscrollbar_update(); 
});
```

does this work?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$('.scrollable').tinyscrollbar().tinyscrollbar_update();
```